# Stuck at "Attached SCSI removable disk" trying to install Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, usb-drive

I bought a new laptop the other day, and now i'm trying to dual boot Linux Mint with Windows 7, which is already installed.

I initially used UNetBootin to put the .iso onto a USB.
Rebooted with the USB, and chose the Live boot option. 
The install seemed to be running fine judging by the rapid rate of text that was flowing past my screen.

It stopped at "[sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk" and refused to continue.

the google search led me to this page, which also has no clear solution.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11792569

I've installed fedora 16 via USB before, so I have at least a little experience.

Here are my specs
Toshiba Qosmio x770
i7 2670 QM
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560M
TOSHIBA SSD 128GB
TOSHIBA HDD 750GB

I've tried 2 USB's so far in different ports and using other software to transfer the files to USB as well. 
I've also tried disconnecting everything but the USB from the other ports as well.

Are there any other options that I haven't considered?

Comment: Do other distros work in this machine, and does the same USB drive work in other machines?

Comment: Linux mint was the first distro I tried to install. I tried to install fedora 16 later but it still gave a similar error. I read something about switchable graphics so I'm wondering if that could be the case, although I know nothing of the topic. I do know that my i7 can function as an integrated graphics card, but that's the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: Check the BIOS setting for your dedicated graphics card. I had to enable mine in order to get the installer to work. This is ironic because although my original install had gone fine, Ubuntu would hang at login until I DISABLED the dedicated GPU (on my Gigabyte laptop that was the "3D graphic Acceleration" setting. FWIW, I was re-installing because a graphics driver install went poorly.